# Connect physical Android Wear watch to emulated phone

Tags: bluetooth, android-emulator, android-wear

I have found many tutorials that explain how to pair an emulated Android Wear watch to a physical phone. However, I would like to do the opposite. Is it possible to create a Bluetooth connection from the pc to the watch and then tell ADB to make the phone emulator use this connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is possible by putting the Android OS on a generic emulator like VirtualBox and using a computer Bluetooth LE dongle. For more infos, see here:
[Bluetooth Low Energy on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27712017/1121352)

Answer (score 3):

You can't is the short answer. The emulator does not support [bluetooth](/questions/tagged/bluetooth) testing at all.

See the [Google Developers post on Using the Emulaor](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

The important line is near the end:

**Emulator Limitations**

The functional limitations of the emulator include:

- No support for placing or receiving actual phone calls. You can
  simulate phone calls (placed and received) through the emulator
  console, however.
- No support for USB connections
- No support for device-attached headphones
- No support for determining network connected state
- No support for determining battery charge level and AC charging state
- No support for determining SD card insert/eject
- **No support for Bluetooth**

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not entirely sure whether that answers my question. I didn't expect the emulator to support bluetooth, i.e. the emulator using the pc's bluetooth module as its own. My idea was that the emulator only has to know that it can reach the wear device through ADB. If I can connect the wear device to my pc over bluetooth, just like I would do with a physical phone, the only thing left to do is tell ADB to set up a connection between these two devices. Does my reasoning make any sense or am I missing something here?

Comment: It can't apparently, but I'm on mobile now so can't cite it.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the Android Wear service on the handset integrates many services to make connecting a watch to the Android handset easy. If you want to connect the watch to your computer, you'll have to replicate this code on the PC. As far as I know, Android Wear is not completely open source, so making that work might be impossible.